# How to sample from six cubemap images for a skybox in Shader Graph?

Tags: unity, skybox, unity-shader-graph

I'm trying to update a skybox shader to URP and reimplement it in Shader Graph.  The shader code itself is pretty straightforward, but I don't know enough about Shader Graph yet to set up the basic skybox.

It's a standard cubemap skybox made up of six textures for +x, -x, +y, -y, +z, and +z.

Trying to Google different variants of "unity shader graph cubemap skybox" turns up tons of noise and nothing actually useful that I can see.

Does anyone know what the basic node setup is I would need to input six images and output a skybox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Assets folder, right click and select `Create > Legacy > Cubemap`

Set the "Face Size" parameter to your desired resolution before you assign your textures - it won't re-import them automatically if you increase the size later.

Assign your six textures to the six face fields.

[image: Cubemap inspector]

Now inside your shader graph, you can add a Cubemap property, and sample it like so:

[image: Cubemap sampling graph]

Assign your custom-made cubemap to the material property.

[Note that you can also pre-compose your six images into a single image in various layouts](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Cubemap.html), and Unity will automatically convert this to a corresponding cubemap based on your import settings. [This gives you additional options to filter the cubemap for use in reflections, and HDR support](https://answers.unity.com/questions/948833/does-legacy-cubemap-mean-it-being-phased-out.html).

Comment: That looks pretty straightforward. Thanks!